# How to delete a folder from a project in android studio

Tags: android, directory

I have accidentally created a asset folder in wrong directory in a project. Now how can I delete the folder?

[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwZmC.jpg)

Comment: right click on the folder name and select delete ?

Comment: there is no delete option. check the screen shot,please.

Comment: @MohammadMarufUddin go to Refactor > Safe Delete

Comment: not nescessarily from the android studio, go to the directories and just delete the directory

Comment: you can delete it from directly from windows explorer. Android studio will automatically detect the changes and update accordingly

Comment: @AshishKumar there is  no delete option, safe delete option is not available from the refractor.

Comment: @AngelKoh , I know that it can be deleted from the explorer but shouldn't there be a method too to delete folder using android studio itself?

Answer (score 1):

Try to switch from "Android" to "Project" in upper left corner and then you can delete your folder.
Maybe that helps you.